# JavaScript Regex mismatch

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this code:

```
var regExp=new RegExp("(\/|-|.)+","g");

var t1=regExp.test(new Date());
alert(t1);//result true

var t2=regExp.test("19/03/1986");
alert(t1);//result true
```

why, first alert, return true value? There is not any charatter defined into regex pattern...

Thanks

Comment: `.` means *any* character. Also, you should learn about char class instead of using alternation groups

Comment: I guess `.` should be `\.`

Comment: And besdies, the `g` modifier should be removed if you only use the regex with `RegExp#test`. The `new Date()` is passed to the regex as `"2016-10-07T08:13:59.703Z"` string that your regex matches *entirely* (since it is equal to `.+`), that is why the second `test` also succeeds.

Comment: The first test would match even with `"(/|-)+"` or `"(/|-|\\.)+"` as there is a `-` inside the input. But you'd better use `var regExp= /[-\/.]/;` here.

Answer (score 1):

`.` means any char in regexp, so any char can match your exp

you can change it to `\d{4}(\/|-|\.)\d{2}(\/|-|\.)\d{2}`

Maybe this can help you understand what you write

[Regexper](https://regexper.com/#(%5C%2F%7C-%7C.)%2B)

[image]

and remove `g`

Comment: "may help you understand" should be a comment, not an answer. An answer should be clear and straight forward, not just inspiring.

Comment: Apologize, I have changed the anwser

Comment: No, `.` does not match *any* char in JS regex. Do *you* understand why `g` should be removed?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
var regExp= /(\/|-|\.)/g;
var t1=regExp.test(new Date());
alert(t1);// return false
var t2=regExp.test("19/03/1986");
alert(t2);// return true
```

Thanks